# Distributor T&Cs appear to conflict with GPL. Is this a violation?

Tags: gpl

I came across [GIMPShop.com](https://www.gimpshop.com/) which distributes an installer for GIMP bundled with some kind of adware:

> Gimpshop.com is distributing the original unmodified software,
>   obtained directly from GIMP's repository website, and does not modify
>   it in any way. These installers comply with the original software
>   manufacturer's policies and terms & conditions. DownloadAdmin™ is an
>   install manager, which manages the installation of your chosen
>   software. In addition to managing your download and installation,
>   DownloadAdmin™will offer free popular software that you may be
>   interested in. You are not required to install any additional software
>   to complete your installation of your selected software. You can
>   always completely remove the programs at any time in Windows'
>   Add/Remove Programs.

There is a "GPL" page on the site:
[GPL page](https://www.gimpshop.com/gpl)

and as far as I know the installation will include this as required. I have not attempted to request the source code from them.

But it seems to me that it conflicts with the terms and conditions page:
[GIMPShop T&Cs page](https://www.gimpshop.com/terms-and-conditions)

for example:

> 2. Use License
>
> a. You can only download one copy of the information or software on
>   Gimpshop.com. The download should be for personal, non-commercial
>   transitory viewing only. This is not a transfer of title, however it
>   is the grant of the license. If you have this license you may not: i.
>   Modify or copy the materials...

Now, presumably they are referring to their installer here and not to GIMP itself, but it seems very vague to me.

Is this a violation that I should report?

Comment: gimpshop.com is a known attack site and distributes trojaned GIMP installers. It is unlikely that the owners care about laws. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMPshop#Status

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IANAL, and IANYL.  That said, they seem to be pretty close to legal.  I think it likely that your reading of their non-free license is correct; that is, it applies only to their installer (though I agree they don't go out of their way to make that clear).  Under the *mere aggregation* doctrine as I understand it, an installer wrapped around GPL software would not itself need to be GPL, so that's not a violation.

GIMP is distributed under GPL3 (or later versions), so as they distribute electronically they are required to make source available "*in the same way through the same place*" as they make their download available.  On [GIMPSHOP's download page](https://www.gimpshop.com/downloads) there is a pretty clear link to the GIMP source on the GIMP project's FTP site.  Sadly, as [the GIMP project makes clear](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/), they

> had a server move a while back that caused us to lose our existing
>   mirrors (moved from physical to virtual server and to an environment
>   that doesn't allow FTP access)

so the link doesn't and won't work.  That **is** a GPL3 violation, but it's also fairly easy to remedy.

In short, I think what they're doing - wrapping GPLed software in a non-free adwared installer - is lame, but with the easily-remedied exception related to their broken link, I think they're in compliance with the GPL as regards GIMP.

Interestingly, they also be out of compliance on [their GPL page](https://www.gimpshop.com/gpl), which shows something they call "*the GIMPSHOP General Public License*" that looks **remarkably** like GPL2 with the original copyright notice filed off, and GIMPSHOP's inserted instead.  As apsillers points out below (many thanks!) [the FSF permits modfications of the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#ModifyGPL), but has certain requirements that GIMPSHOP have overlooked.  That could be remedied, but at the moment it's clearly in violation of the FSF's copyright in the GPL.

Comment: In short, this looks like another relatively easy fix: cut the preamble, and make the title on the page "GIMPSHOP General Public License" instead of "General Public License"

Comment: @apsillers I had not previously read those instructions - thank you for that!  They would need to modify the instructions at the end as well, but broadly I agree with you and have modified my answer accordingly.